# Marklogic Optimistic locking using XCC API

Tags: marklogic

We are using XCC to communicate to Marklogic. We wanted to implement optimistic locking. This is to ensure noone has updated on stale data.

I see there are some documentation around implementing this using Java API.

Can someone please help me in understanding if  Optimistic locking is possible using XCC API and redirect me how to do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Optimistic Locking](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/transactions#id_81051) in the Java Application Developer's guide.  Since optimistic locking is implemented in the REST API, XCC cannot benefit since it does not build on the REST API.  Rather than do optimistic locking in XCC you would keep a Session (transaction) open to ensure that you're updating a consistent version of the document.